# Is there a way to plug in the concrete example into the visualization for these four subspaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

This is Gilbert Strang's four subspaces of a matrix

[image]

Is there a way to plug in the concrete example into the visualization for these four subspaces?

for instance, to svd this matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

we use the eigendecomposition of this matrix 
$$\begin{bmatrix}1 & 2 & 0\\1 & 2 & 0\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
2 & 2 \\
0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
=
\displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}5 & 5\\5 & 5\end{matrix}\right]$$

In this process, is there a way to plug in the matrix $\displaystyle \left[\begin{matrix}5 & 5\\5 & 5\end{matrix}\right]$
 into the visualization for these four subspaces?

one valid [SVD](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=SVD%20%7B%7B1,%201%7D,%20%7B2,%202%7D,%20%7B0,%200%7D%7D) for this matrix would be

[image]

$u_2, u_3$ are one of orthonormal bases of the null space of $A^T$.

is there a way to visualize this null space of $A^T$?

Comment: Why should the SVD have anything to do with visualizing the four subspaces?

Comment: By the way: one valid SVD for this matrix would be
$$
A = \pmatrix{1/\sqrt{2} & 1/\sqrt{2}\\ \cdot & \cdot} \pmatrix{\sqrt{10}&0\\0&0\\0&0}
\pmatrix{1/\sqrt{5}&\cdot&\cdot\\2/\sqrt{5} &\cdot & \cdot\\0 & \cdot & \cdot}
$$
where the $\cdot$s are entries chosen so that the matrices on the right an left are orthogonal (these can be found using Gram-Schmidt, for instance).

Comment: thanks for your comments, I've updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $A$ is $m \times n$ with rank $r$ (i.e. $r$ is the number of non-zero singular values), and suppose $A = U \Sigma V^T$ is a singular value decomposition.

In this case, the first $r$ columns of $U$ form a basis (an orthonormal basis) of the column-space, and the remaining $m-r$ columns form a basis of the null-space of $A^T$.  The first $r$ columns of $V$ form a basis of the row-space, and the remaining $n-r$ columns of $V$ form a basis of the null-space of $A$.

I'm not quite sure if this helps you "visualize" anything, but perhaps this is the kind of thing you're looking for.